# How to convert int to hex and hex to int to get the following values?

Tags: javascript, numbers, int, hex

I'm having trouble understanding this converting from hex to int and int to hex. How does the value `6713707` or `6,713,707` equal `0x66716b`? How does one go from one to the other?

This is what I see in my debugger:

[image]

If I add the red, green and blue together I get:

```
102 + 113 + 107 = 322;
```

If I multiply those three values I get:

```
102 * 113 * 107 = 1,233,282;
```

Where is the number `6713707` coming from? Can you show me your work?

**Background:**
I'm working with colors and in HTML and CSS you use #FF0000 to represent red. But in JavaScript and ActionScript when you access those colors they return as int and numbers.

Comment: "If I multiply those three values I get" --- and you multiply them because ...? When you have decimal `111` it's not equal to `1 * 1 * 1` for sure, but to `1 * 100 + 1 * 10 + 1 * 1`

Answer (score 1):

0x66716b is just the concatenation if the red (66), green (67) and blue (6b) hex values, 0x is a way of saying "this is hex not decimal" (which is why there are [0x##] values next to the decimal in your debugger)

I'm quite sure that 6713707 is what you get if you turn 66716b in hex to decimal, I.e. 1 x b (b=11) + 16 x 6 + 256 x 1 + 4096 x 7 + .... (I don't have a calculator to make certain/do the rest).

Hope I've helped!

Answer (score 0):

The RGB values are three eight-bit values, which form the low 24 bits of a 32-bit value (the high eight bits are sometimes referred to as the "alpha channel"). So your full 32-bit hex value is 0x0066716b. [Converting hex to decimal](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) gives the value 6713707.

Comment: Can explain more how that works? I've seen the converters before. I want to see the work.